# How can two event listeners work in parallel?

Tags: jquery

I am generating dynamic ids for my div which shows a (+) plus button an image as shown below

```
<div id="'+random_number+'" class="inc buttontest">+</div><div class="dec buttontest">-</div>
```

On click of that , i am registering with the above class using .

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".buttontest", function() {



});
```

On click of the plus button , how can i multiply with the value  present in other event listener .

If you see the image , on click of the plus button , the value 75.00 must be 75*2 that is  150 .

Please se the js fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/u8Vft/2/

[image]

Could anybody please help me . I dont have any idea how to go furher with this .

Answer (score 2):

On Click of `plus/minus` button check for class `inc/dec` and then decide to `multiply/subtract` respectively like:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".buttontest", function() {
    var $id = $(this).prevAll("input").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).hasClass("inc")){
        $(".cart").find("div").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id_attr")==$id){
       $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10)+amountdd);
            }
        });
    }else if($(this).hasClass("dec")){
        $(".cart").find("div").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id_attr")==$id){
            $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(),10)-amountdd);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Vft/10/)**

Comment: on click of plus button , I will have accsess to  amountdd and multiply accordingly ,  but how can i update that  to HTML.append('<div>'+amountdd+'</div>'); ??

Comment: @PreethiJain: Can you share your multiplication code in fiddle?

Comment: Select a checkbox and then click on plus button then you will get an alert , please see the fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/u8Vft/5/

Comment: That updated amount , i need to update it to the div HTML.append('<div>'+amountdd+'</div>');

Comment: Please let me know if that is possible or do the whole structure needs to be changed .

Comment: @PreethiJain: Glad it helped. Please go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work